# Wicket Security - Change Roles of an Inmemory User

Tags: spring-security, wicket, wicket-7

I'm using Wicket 7.0 in an application I'm developing and I would like some advice regarding using Inmemory-users during development.

The idea is to have one single Inmemory user whom I set the roles of right before I log in.

My first intended approach is to instantiate the user at startup with "username" and password but without any roles. Then I would like to add/remove roles through ticking Checkboxes in a component in the Login-form and finally log in with the predefined user/pwd.

Can an instance of an Inmemory-user have it's roles changed when the application is running? Or should I delete it and create a new instance of it everytime I want it to have different roles? Is this even the best and simplest way to go about ti?

This is only during development for convenience.

Thanks in advance

Comment: with scriptcode and some shown error you question stays out of the downvote zone.

Answer (score 0):

Inject `UserDetailsManager` and use its `updateUser()` method to update its roles:

```
@Service
public class SingleUserSwitchService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

    public void changeUserRoles(String ... roles) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles = ... // new roles
        User user = new User("login", "password", roles);
        userDetailsManager.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

Here, I assume that your user login is 'login' and you hardcode the password.

Then you just need to call your service with the list of the desired roles.